# VBA cut entire row and paste in next column on change

Tags: excel, vba, insert, rows

Currently VBA inserts a new row on change of value. How to I change so that it just move down one column without inserting new rows. I'm trying to keep everything on one page.

For example:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dS9rG.png)

`Sub InsertRowsAtValueChange()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim WorkRng As Range 
    On Error Resume Next
    xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, 
    Type:=8)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = WorkRng.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
    If WorkRng.Cells(i, 1).Value <> WorkRng.Cells(i - 1, 1).Value Then
        WorkRng.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Insert
    End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub`

Comment: ...on change of what?  Also, what's the `Update` function?  Note that `On Error Resume Next` is not a good idea for regular use. (You're telling Excel that you "don't even care" if there's an error)

Comment: Thank you I will adjust. Just with change of a value, looking to have it move down one cell. See photo I added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to understand where you want to paste the entire row. You will receive an error if you copy an entire row then try to paste it to Column B. Maybe the code below will help you. Destination is where you want the entire row to placed.

```
Dim ws as Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    WorkRng.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=ws.Cells(i, 1)
```